Confused about definition of 2-category of categories over $\mathcal{C}$
Let $\mathcal{C}$ be a category.
Here the following definition is given for the 2-category of categories over $\mathcal{C}$.

The 2-category of categories over $\mathcal{C}$ is the 2-category defined as follows:

Its objects will be functors $p: \mathcal{S}\to \mathcal{C}$.
Its 1-morphisms $(\mathcal{S},p)\to (\mathcal{S}',p')$ will be functors $G: \mathcal{S}\to \mathcal{S}$ such that $p'\circ G=p$.
Its 2-morphisms $t: G\to H$ for $G,H:(\mathcal{S},p)\to (\mathcal{S}',p')$ will be morphisms of functors such that $p'(t_x)=\mathrm{id}_{p(x)}$


I am confused about the third point. Why is $p'(t_x)=\mathrm{id}_{p(x)}$ the correct definition, rather than, $p'(t_x)\cong\mathrm{id}_{p(x)}$?

Both sides are morphisms in the 1-category $\mathcal{C}$, so isomorphism between them makes no sense; you can only talk about equality.
